# Maximum of IO(Int) list

Tags: haskell

I have the following sample code

```
let x = [return 1::IO(Int), return 2::IO(Int)]
```

So x is a list of IO(Int)s.
maximum is a function which returns the maximum of a list, if the things in the list are Ords.
How do I "map" maximum to run on this list of IO(Int)s?

Comment: Just a tiny tip, Haskell types don't need parentheses to "apply" them, they are just like functions: `IO Int` is fine (but parens are needed in `IO (Maybe Int)` to group the inner expression). :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asequence) the array into `IO [Int]` and then run [`maximum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amaximum) on it using [`liftM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3aliftM):

```
liftM maximum (sequence yourList) :: IO Int
```

Answer (score 9):

The key point here is that you cannot compare `IO` actions, only the values
that result from those actions. To perform the comparison, you have to perform
those actions to get back a list of the results. Fortunately, there is
a function that does just that: `sequence :: (Monad m) => [m a] -> m [a]`.
This takes a list of actions and performs them in order to produce an action
that gives a list of results.

To compute the maximum, you would do something like

```
x = [return 1::IO(Int), return 2::IO(Int)]
...
biggest = maximum `fmap` sequence x :: IO [Int]
```